# Non-US Teen taking US domestic flight without ID

Tags: usa, paperwork, domestic-travel

This is a current situation we're trying to find solutions for.

My 17yo son has been in Florida for a week with friends, and is about to come home (flying to San Diego).  Luckily the flight today has been delayed (well, was canceled and rebooked for tomorrow night) as he has realised his bag, containing his only IDs (NZ passport and a SENTRI card) were left in the car that dropped them at the airport.  They have so far been unable to reach the driver of the car.

What options does my son have, if any, to fly without his ID if they can't reach the driver?  He has travel insurance.  Everyone else he is flying with are US citizens, however my son is not a US citizen (is in US on B2 visa).  I have a scanned copy of the ID page of his NZ passport (but not of his US visa), and a scanned copy of his Mexico Residency ID card - if I send him those to display on his phone would/could that help?  Or is he stuck and we have to make some other travel arrangements?

Comment: If he has a checked bag, he'll need to show ID to the airline agent to allow him to check in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What identification does a teenager need to pass a TSA checkpoint?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/116427/what-identification-does-a-teenager-need-to-pass-a-tsa-checkpoint)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Technically, children under 18 are not required to provide ID when going through TSA airport security checkpoints. See [this page](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification):

> Children
>
> TSA does not require children under 18 to provide identification when
> traveling within the United States. Contact the airline for questions
> regarding specific ID requirements for travelers under 18.

(although how he would prove that he is under 18 without ID, I don't know).

He is unlikely to encounter immigration checkpoints where he has to prove his immigration status, when flying domestically.

Answer (score 6):

He would probably be able to board the flight to San Diego without any ID or just with the scanned picture on the phone (he will very likely go through a significantly more intrusive security scan than usual).

Getting home however, whether it is New Zealand or Mexico, may be tricky without these documents.

The nearest NZ consulate seems to be in [Los Angeles](https://www.mfat.govt.nz/en/countries-and-regions/americas/united-states-of-america/new-zealand-consulate-general-los-angeles/), 2-12 hours drive from San Diego (depending on the traffic). Mexico has a consulate in [San Diego](https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/sandiego/). He'll need to inquire with these consulates as to what he needs to return to either of these countries and how he'd go about getting it.

Comment: Getting into Mexico from San Diego won't be a problem, if he can get to SD.

Comment: Is that "two to twelve hours"?

Comment: @phoog yeah. I've made the San Diego to LA stretch of I-5 in two hours before (don't tell the CHP), and I've also stood on I-405 for hours just getting from Orange County to LAX. LA traffic is rather unpredictable.

Comment: @Midavalo: Note that his I-94 (and potentially that of any of his traveling companions) could get messed up [if he goes to Mexico by land](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/93523/39667) (and if he goes by air, then he will *definitely* need a passport).

Comment: @Kevin we live in Mexico, crossing the border into Mexico isn't a problem

Comment: @Midavalo why are you so certain? Have you been able to cross the border into Mexico without any documents before?

Comment: @littlead yes, hundreds of times

Comment: @Midavalo: That is not what I was pointing out. My concern is that, next time he tries to travel to the US, CBP may decide that he "overstayed" because his exit was never reported.

Comment: @Kevin our exits are never reported when we drive across the border

Comment: @Midavalo to satisfy my curiosity - how? I couldn't find any reference on any mexian or US site that would tell me how to cross the border into mexico with no documents

Comment: @littleadv To drive into Mexico you are not stopped by INM (Mexican immigration), so you do not need to show any documents to enter the country.  Legally you are required to have travel documents of some sort, but there is no check to enforce it.  If you are stopped (we haven't been stopped for a very long time) it is by SAT (not INM) - effectively a customs stop to check for items you may be bringing in, but they never ask for travel documents